# Шкаф по уходу за одеждой

Tags: словосочетания

Допустимо ли словосочетание «паровой шкаф по уходу за одеждой»
шкаф по уходу можно ли так говорить

Answer (score 2):

До сих пор существовало  выражение "средства по уходу за лицом, за волосами, за одеждой и т.д.", пока не появился "паровой шкаф по уходу за одеждой."

**Примечание** (для чего нужен такой шкаф): "У меня целый шкаф  одежды, за которой  нужно как-то ухаживать. Поэтому я купила эту «пароварку», которая помогает мне держать в порядке платья из дорогой и деликатной ткани. Плюс тут можно детские вещи от микробов избавить и даже запахи удалить из одежды. А усилий никаких для этого не нужно: просто развешиваю одежду, выбираю режим и дальше этот шкаф делает все сам".

**Пока существуют два варианта названий**: "паровой шкаф по уходу за одеждой" и "паровой шкаф для ухода за одеждой". Желательно остановиться **на втором варианте, ввиду функциональной сложности агрегата.** Сравнить: стиральная машина ― машина для стирки белья.

Можно предположить, что выражение "средство по уходу за одеждой" чисто формально применили для названия этого многофункционального шкафа.

Answer (score 1):

Нет-нет, тут это невозможно совершенно.

Во-первых, смысл непонятен. Шкаф в котором осуществляется уход за одеждой? Тогда - для.

Во-вторых, сама грамматика предлога "ПО" не позволяет подобного ни в каком значении. "Шкаф для одежды" - это понятно, платяной шкаф. Могу допустить "шкаф для ухода за одеждой" (это если шкаф необычный, не мебельный, а предназначенный исключительно для чистки, скажем, одежды, у вас видимо, о чем-то подобном и идет речь), но "шкаф по уходу" - никак.

Вообще предлог "ПО" (в этом значении) при управлении существительными возможен только в сочетаниях "руководство по", "инструкция по", "задачник по" - т. е. когда управляющее существительное прямо или косвенно обозначает некое действие или указание. В остальных случаях - или значение другое ("двигаться по поверхности", "сумки по пять рублей" и т. д.), или конструкция ошибочна.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре подобных примеров не нашёл. А что мешает употребить обычное "для"? В данном контексте оно подходит лучше, чем любой другой предлог.